# types of variable in java

Tags: java, types

Is there a way to get the *type* of variable in java ? ? 
 my goal is to define If the variable is `int` or `String`

There is a way I tried to use before but it didn't work with `int`. It is just for `String`

This is code :

```
String a="121212aa";
System.out.println(a.getClass().isInstance(a));
```

*`a`* now is String and the result will be `java.lang.String`.

i need to check also if it's `int` 
because if I use `Boolean`  with *else* in it 
maybe the input is `double`

Comment: You should already know this when you examine where `a` was defined.  Java is strongly typed, so unless you're talking about generics, you should already *know* what type the variable is.

Comment: look that not my real example because the example is project and there is a form in the first hand and  sqlite in the other 
i need to check if the user put in his form int not String 
 i use lanterna library interface

Comment: You should probably add your actual example, as from this alone it's hard to infer what you really need.  I maintain that since Java is strongly typed, you have *a priori* knowledge of what your variable type will be.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Java there are primitive and reference types.

**Primitive types are boxed into wrapper types. You should check against the proper wrapper type**, e.g.:

```
Object i = 1;
i.getClass(); // will return java.lang.Integer
```

Comment: i can't use this way because i didn't use object now
i need exactly int a= 10 ; and the other code

Comment: Provide the example, it's not obvious what you mean.

Comment: i can't provide you the example because it's big but i have  a form in the first hand and sqlite in the other i need to check if the user put in his form int and not  not String  before i send it to my database 
i use lanterna library interface